# TCP fields with SCAPY

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, scapy

i'm trying to extract some information from networking connections using SCAPY. I need to extract some fields from TCP packet header, in fact Receiver Windows Field (WIN), Retransmission Time Out field (RTO), Max Segment field (MSS) and the Options field (OPT).

I'm a bit lost. I'm using Python3 and SCAPY 2.4.3

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

On a TCP packet you can access the following fields: [image]

like `print(packet.options)` and so on